# Blazor - Reload Grid component

Tags: blazor

I created the razor page with add and display values in grid in same page. While adding the records, it is saving in database but after saving the records grid is not refreshed. I need to reload the grid component only since i need to display success message in same page.

Here is my code:

Grid.razor:

```
    @typeparam TableItem

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="blazor-grid-header">@GridHeader</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in ItemList)
        {
<tr class="blazor-row-item">@GridRow(item)</tr>}
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="pagination">

    <button class="btn pagebutton btn-info" onclick=@(new Action(async () => SetPagerSize("back")))>&laquo;</button>
    <button class="btn pagebutton btn-secondary" onclick=@(new Action(async () => NavigateToPage("previous")))>Prev</button>

    @for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
    {
        var currentPage = i;
<button class="btn pagebutton @(currentPage==curPage?"currentpage":"")" onclick=@(new Action(async () => updateList(currentPage)))>
    @currentPage
</button>}

    <button class="btn pagebutton btn-secondary" onclick=@(new Action(async () => NavigateToPage("next")))>Next</button>
    <button class="btn pagebutton btn-info" onclick=@(new Action(async () => SetPagerSize("forward")))>&raquo;</button>

    <span class="pagebutton btn btn-link disabled">Page @curPage of @totalPages</span>

</div>

@functions { int totalPages;
    int curPage;
    int pagerSize;

    int startPage;
    int endPage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Header for BlazorGrid.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment GridHeader { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rows for BlazorGrid.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TableItem> GridRow { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of item supplied to the BlazorGrid.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TableItem> Items { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Size of each page of BlazorGrid. This is a required field.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TableItem> ItemList { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        pagerSize = 5;
        curPage = 1;

        ItemList = Items.Skip((curPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
        totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(Items.Count() / (decimal)PageSize);

        SetPagerSize("forward");
    }

    public void updateList(int currentPage)
    {
        ItemList = Items.Skip((currentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
        curPage = currentPage;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void SetPagerSize(string direction)
    {
        if (direction == "forward" && endPage < totalPages)
        {
            startPage = endPage + 1;
            if (endPage + pagerSize < totalPages)
            {
                endPage = startPage + pagerSize - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                endPage = totalPages;
            }
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
        else if (direction == "back" && startPage > 1)
        {
            endPage = startPage - 1;
            startPage = startPage - pagerSize;
        }
    }

    public void NavigateToPage(string direction)
    {
        if (direction == "next")
        {
            if (curPage < totalPages)
            {
                if (curPage == endPage)
                {
                    SetPagerSize("forward");
                }
                curPage += 1;
            }
        }
        else if (direction == "previous")
        {
            if (curPage > 1)
            {
                if (curPage == startPage)
                {
                    SetPagerSize("back");
                }
                curPage -= 1;
            }
        }

        updateList(curPage);
    } }
```

PlantMaster.razor:

```
 @page "/"
    @inherits PlantMasterBase


<h3>Plants</h3>

<Alert @ref="AlertMessage" Color="Color.Success">
    <Heading>
        Success
        <CloseButton @onclick="AlertMessage.Hide" />
    </Heading>

    @if (AlertMode == "Add")
    {
        <Paragraph>
            Plant has been added successfully...
        </Paragraph>
    }
    else
    {
        <Paragraph>
            Plant has been updated successfully...
        </Paragraph>
    }
</Alert>

    <EditForm Model="@Plant">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="plantName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Plant Name:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="plantName" class="form-control" placeholder="Plant Name" @bind-Value="Plant.PlantName"></InputText>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Address:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" @bind-Value="Plant.Address"></InputText>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="AddClick" @onclick="Add_Click">Add</button>
    </EditForm>

    @if (Plants == null)
    {
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    }
    else
    {
        <Grid Items="@Plants" PageSize="5">
            <GridHeader>
                <th>PlantName</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </GridHeader>
            <GridRow>
                <td>@context.PlantName</td>
                <td>@context.Address</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @onclick="(() => ShowModal(context.PlantId))">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </GridRow>
        </Grid>
    }

    @code{
    public IEnumerable<Plant> Plants { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Plants = await GetPlants();
    }

    protected async Task Add_Click()
    {
        await PlantRepository.AddPlant(Plant);
        Plants = await GetPlants();
        AlertMessage.Show();
        AlertMode = "Add";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this reload issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And for a third attempt, add this to your Grid's @functions:

```
protected override void OnParamtersSet()
{
    // from OnInit, refactor it
    ItemList = Items.Skip((curPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
    totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(Items.Count() / (decimal)PageSize);
}
```

and when that works you can remove all StateHasChanged() calls.

---

On a second look, you might have a differ problem. Try using @key:

```
@foreach (var item in ItemList)
{
  <tr @key="item" class="blazor-row-item">@GridRow(item)</tr>
}
```

---

It's a little hard to decode but the use of `new Action(...)` is curious, I can't imagine what that is good for. Certainly not in combination with async.

I notice that your Grid still uses `@functions` which suggests it is very old and therefore suspect.

So, replace

```
 onclick=@(new Action(async () => updateList(currentPage)))
```

with

```
 onclick="@() => updateList(currentPage)"
```

and see how that works.

Comment: well, keep the change anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Henk Holterman. But this is also not working @Key

Comment: I hope you used a small `k`

Comment: If we use both, not reloading

Comment: Great Henk Holterman. OnParamtersSet is working fine. Since the page size is 5, the data is refreshing till 5 records. From 6th record is not reloaded. For that where i need to do the changes.

Comment: That would involve triggering a NextPage I think. Add some code or parameter to always go to the last page from Add_Click(). A bit messy because you now have to control currentPage from the Parent Component somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your support Henk Holterman. Once set the endpage is 0 in OnParametersSet, all scenarios are working. Really I would like to thank you once again. I tried this scenario around a day.

protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // from OnInit, refactor it
        endPage = 0;
        ItemList = Items.Skip((curPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
        totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(Items.Count() / (decimal)PageSize);

        SetPagerSize("forward");
    }

Answer (score 1):

use 'this.StateHasChanged();` to reload the Blazor UI

```
    void RefreshMe()
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Task.Run() and InvokeAsyn() cancel each other out, and always avoid `async void`. The second part isn't very good advice.

Comment: It's not reloading

Comment: we use it to refresh the ui manully https://blazor-tutorial.net/refresh-ui-manually

Comment: You are correct. If we use same component in same page, its working fine. But my scenario is that I created the Grid.razor as separate and used that component in Blazor UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool showGrid=true;
if(showGrid)
    {
    <Grid Items="@Plants" PageSize="5">
                <GridHeader>
                    <th>PlantName</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </GridHeader>
                <GridRow>
                    <td>@context.PlantName</td>
                    <td>@context.Address</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @onclick="(() => ShowModal(context.PlantId))">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </GridRow>
            </Grid>
    }
```

And when you want to refresh your grid somewhere;

```
showGrid = false;
showGrid = true;
```

Just an idea.